# ZFS on enterprise storage systems

Tags: filesystems, storage, zfs

Enterprise storage, like systems from EMC, NetApp, etc., have their own algorithms and methods for assuring no data is lost. In the scenario of having a bunch of servers attached to such a storage system, will there be any advantages to be had if I use ZFS as a file system? Won't the storage's own capabilities provide the best feasible data integrity, compression, deduplication etc., rendering redundant all my efforts? Thus, wouldn't XFS, UFS or some other file system be preferable in this case?

Comment: What’s wrong with more redundancy? Are you sure these storage systems will detect bit rot?

Comment: They do detect bit rot and much more, it's what they're built for. ZFS on the other hand shines when used on commodity hardware; and without having access to the bare metal, i.e. the HDs, it cannot prevent bit rot or anything for that matter. Besides, it consumes CPU and RAM, which always come at a price. That is the question after all, does ZFS or any other "magic" file system have any effect when used on enterprise storage, or not?

Comment: ZFS can *always* detect bit rot, it’s what it’s made for. To correct it, it needs redundancy at the ZFS level, of course. However, ZFS offers more than reliability and integrity, like nested file systems, compression, snapshots, send/receive etc. I suggest you concentrate on that and then decide if these are required *for your use case*.

Comment: Let's accept ZFS will detect bit rot no matter what, but this is not the question here. Besides nested file systems, every other service mentioned plus many more is provided by enterprise storage systems. What I am trying to understand here is, is there a scenario in which a file system like ZFS would provide a useful service when combined with a high end storage system? Or would a simpler file system provide better value for money?

Comment: Storage systems that present block devices for other systems to use as disk drives work with raw bytes. That's all. Snapshots and replication by such storage systems are not guaranteed to be a coherent copy of an actual file system and the data it holds.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Henle said, you have basically no guarantees that this black-box storage system does what you want. Of course, it is likely that it already does everything you want, maybe even that it uses ZFS internally, but you don't know for sure. And even if you know exactly, you most likely cannot configure it completely to your liking.

So, you have basically three different possible situations you can find yourself in:

1. You don't know anything about the system and you cannot configure it in any meaningful way. Most cloud storage would fall in this case, as would storage systems in large corporations where you just get "storage" of a certain size by requesting it if you need it for your projects.
2. You know how the system works and is configured, but you cannot configure it yourself.
3. You know how it works and can actively modify it (either yourself via granted privileges or by telling the admin to do it). Most likely in smaller operations where you know each other or where people know that different needs should be met.

That leads to the following answers to the question "Is having ZFS on top beneficial, just a waste, or even problematic?":

1. As you have no guarantees, you gain nearly all features at the sole drawback of performance. You may need to benchmark and test a lot to find out how the system works, but it may be that you never get good enough performance. Of course, it could be all in vain, but as you don't know, you stay on the safe side.
2. Like 1, but now that you know how it works, you can optimize for performance much better, or in the worst case know why your performance is bad. You also know what features you already have, so you can make a more informed decision if the ZFS features are worth it in your case.
3. Like 2, but now that you can actively configure and optimize the storage system, it is even more likely that you don't need ZFS on top. And even if you do, you maybe can align both to minimize performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

Research from CERN shows that even very expensive storage systems suffers from bit rot. Further, their research shows that ZFS does not suffer from bit rot. Also, independent comp sci researchers also shows that ZFS does not suffer from bit rot. This is the reason CERN has switched to ZFS. Also, IBM Sequoia supercomputer, uses Lustre to store 55 Petabyte data. Lustre is a parallel storage system, that uses ZFS for the actual storage on disk. Google CERN and ZFS and you will see lot of research papers on data integrity. Also, wikipedia article on ZFS has research papers on data integrity.

Comment: All magnetic media suffer from bit rot, and that's exactly the sort of problem storage systems (not JBODs) solve. They use various techniques to achieve this, like periodic scrubbing, checksumming, etc. Lustre is a different thing, not used within a storage but used to create a cluster from storages.

Obviously if I buy a JBOD, even an expensive one, I'll use ZFS, but in the case of a high end storage system, it does not seem beneficial, in the classical sense.

Comment: Nope, they do not use various techniques to achieve protection against bit rot. Or, some of them try, but fail. For instance, some Enterprise storage disks has DIF protection to combat bit rot.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Integrity_Field
However, if you look at the spec sheets of said enterprise disk, you will see "1 irrecoverable error per 10^16 bits read" which means even DIF data protected enterprise disks, are not safe. I encourage you to check the spec sheets of very high end Fibre Channel disks, DIF disks, SAS disks, etc. They all have bit rot. This includes raid cards, etc.